# How to change font in/ add font to anaconda?

Tags: python, fonts, anaconda

I just finished installing anaconda(for Windows) the first time, and find the default font of the Prompt not that beautiful. So I tried changing the font in  setting but it turned out there are just two kinds of font. How can I add another font into it? In the regedit?

Answer (score 0):

There is a gorgeous new open-source replacement for command prompt in Windows, which has all sorts of amazing fonts, called **Windows Terminal** developed by Microsoft (!) and available for free on [GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal) or [at the Microsoft Store](https://apps.microsoft.com/store/detail/windows-terminal/9N0DX20HK701).

[image: Windows Terminal screenshot]

After installing Windows Terminal, to get it running an anaconda environment, you need to run `C:\anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat` [or wherever it is on your computer].

Instead of doing this every time, it's best to set up a "profile" so it will start automatically.  To do this I followed these steps on [Arturo Moncada-Torres' blog](https://arturomoncadatorres.com/incorporating-anaconda-prompt-windows-terminal/):

[image]

Edit your settings JSON to have these lines:

```
    "profiles": 
    {
        "defaults": 
        {
            "startingDirectory": "C:\\Users\\mc\\Desktop\\GitHub\\"
        },
        "list": 
        [
            {
                "colorScheme": "One Half Dark",
                "commandline": "cmd.exe /K C:\\anaconda3\\Scripts\\activate.bat C:\Users\mc\.conda\envs\env4",
                "font": 
                {
                    "face": "Consolas"
                },
                "guid": "{insert-a-GUID-here}",
                "hidden": false,
                "historySize": 30000,
                "icon": "C:\\anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\conda\\shell\\conda_icon.ico",
                "name": "Anaconda",
                "startingDirectory": "C:\\GitHub\\",
                "useAtlasEngine": true
            },
```

where `env4` is the name of the environment you'd like the Terminal to start in.  (just omit everything after `activate.bat` if you are fine with the Terminal starting in the `base` environment)

To generate a GUID, run the command `New-Guid` in powershell.

Test that fancy fonts work by running:

```
pip install alive_progress
python -m alive_progress.tools.demo
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use regedit to add a font to Anaconda.
go to settings > terminal > fonts
select the dropdown menu under fonts and select custom
you should have an option to 'Browse'...use this to select your font